# Is it possible to locally reverse engineer a ReactJS component starting from a prod bundle.js model, and if so, how?

Tags: reactjs

I have been working with a client to finish a project that the original developer left with some glaring holes. The front end is built using `ReactJS`, so I cloned the repo I was asked to use. Once I finally got it working, I noticed the prod site had 1 feature that my local site did not.
To make a long story short, I found that the prod bundle.js included:

```
var MissingComponentFromGitHubRepo = require('./MissingComponentFromGitHubRepo'); // plus associated functionality from that component
```

The original developer does not seem to know where the component file is (and the client wonders why the heck it isn't in the repo), and the client does not want to lose the functionality it enables on the prod site. So I am trying to reverse engineer the component from bundle.js.

***Can a component be reverse engineered from a bundle.js model?*** Is it just a matter of finding all references in bundle.js to the missing component, bringing in all of these pieces, adding require() statements, and exporting the module?

The good thing is I can compare my local to prod until (if possible), it matches the functionality on prod, at which point I would assume the component has effectively been "rebuilt".

Comment: The question doesn't contain enough data. What is prod bundle? Is it minified? Do you have source maps for it?

Comment: Not minified. The prod file, bundle.js, was built locally by previous dev using a gulp file which bundles changes, then dev manually exported to website which was being hosted by a web hosting service. No source map as far as I can tell

Comment: Then I suppose it's as simple as finding the component in bundled JS and extracting the module from there. It's hard to suggest anything more specific without seeing what things look there.

Comment: OK - fair enough. Sorry I have nothing else I can add - I'll just give it a shot and see what happens